# With setOnMarkerClickListener, how do I get the marker's screen coordinates?

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am drawing markers on a GoogleMap using @capacitor/google-maps in an ionic/angular web app.

When the user clicks on a map marker, I want a small info popup at that marker, i.e., just like the Google Maps "InfoWindow". This Capacitor wrapper does not provide a way to show the InfoWindow, so I rolled my own with Ionic's popover; code below.

Now my problem is that the popover always shows in the center of the screen. The onSetMarkerClickListener callback passes the marker, but this object doesn't have anything related to the click event, from which I can get the screen coordinates, to position the popover. I did `console.log(marker)` to inspect this object.

How can I position the popover exactly where the map marker is located?

```
  await this.newMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(async (marker) => {
  console.log(marker);
  const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
     component: MapMarkerPopupComponent,
     componentProps: { markerTitle: marker.title }
  });
  await popover.present();
  popover.onDidDismiss();
});
```

I am hoping for an answer that'll let me stick with this (Capacitor) API, but if necessary I could use a different maps API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the event through the method.

```
(click)="presentPopover($event)

presentPopover(e: Event) {
  this.popover.event = e;
}
```

passing the `$event` argument should place the popover where it was clicked. Heres more info from the docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover#isopen-property

Comment: Thanks, but then how to know which marker was clicked? Using `setOnMarkerClickListener` passes the marker as a parameter.